# Mark three Horizontal line as Day Highs, provided each is higher than the other in historical sense

Tags: pine-script

Problem is when i run this code it gives high of each daily candle, if i use var function to define the counters, the it plots nothing and gives study error. Please help.

```
//@version=5
//Defining indicator settings here
indicator("High Levels", overlay=true)

//Locking the daily timeframe for finding out the values of High, Low & Close
High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)
Close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)

// Mark Horizontal Line for Previous Day values
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    hLine=line.new(bar_index, High, bar_index+10, High, color=color.black, width = 2, extend= extend.both)
    lLine=line.new(bar_index, Low, bar_index+10, Low, color=color.white, width = 2, extend= extend.both)

// Counter for highs and lows
//lookBack = 1 // counter for the for function
previousHigh = 2
confirmedHigh = 1

// Get the highest High previously

for i = 0 to 2
    if High[previousHigh] > High[confirmedHigh]                   // This will lock the highest bar as confirmedHigh and keep looking till previousHigh
        hLine1=line.new(bar_index, High, bar_index+10, High, color=color.black, width = 2, extend= extend.both)
        previousHigh := previousHigh + 1
        confirmedHigh := confirmedHigh + 1
        if (confirmedHigh>4)
            break
    else
        lookBack := lookBack +1
        previousHigh := previousHigh + 1
```